# "Selection does not contain a main type"-errors appearing out of nowhere (they can be solved by restarting Eclipse). Why?

Tags: java, eclipse

It sometimes happens when I'm working on a project that I suddenly get problems with running the program. When I press the keyboard shortcut for running as a Java application, I get the error message "Selection does not contain a main type". Also, the option Run -> Run As -> Java Application has disappeared from the menu.

I CAN, however, run the application by selecting the appropriate command in the menu Run -> Run History, or by running it in debug mode. I can also solve the problem (temporarily, until the next time it appears) by restarting Eclipse. So it seems likely that this is a bug in Eclipse.

I've searched SO and the web for the same problem, but only found examples of people actually forgetting the main class etc.. To emphasize, I don't need to change anything in the code or any settings in Eclipse to fix the problem.

Any idea of why this problem appears, what I can do to prevent it and/or more convenient ways of solving it (restarting Eclipse takes a while) would be much appreciated!

(Additional info as follows. I have no idea if this has anything to do with anything or if it is any help: The last time the problem appeared, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key had just stopped working. Curiously, only in Eclipse and only in one editor tab. Closing and reopening the relevant class tab solved the problem but introduced the "main class not found"-error. This error only affects one project at a time: other projects run perfectly fine)

Comment: I guess that when you get this error, the class currently displayed on screen has no main method. You need to open your main class first, before being able to use the shortcut.

Comment: It does! The same class is open all along. Even when I right-click the correct class in the Package Explorer and select Run As - Java Application, it fails.

Comment: Any extra errors in your error log?  Also, you don't happen to have AJDT installed?

Comment: I don't have AJDT, no. Regarding the error log, I'll have to get back to you the next time the problem arises.